# Finalizar sesión sin afectar otras en PHP

Tags: php

Amigos, estoy haciendo sistema de login donde se logean 50 estudiantes al mismo tiempo, para almacenar sus nombres, id, etc lo hago en variables de session para pasarlos entre archivos php.
La cuestión viene cuando un estudiante finaliza su sesión, llama al archivo logout.php y destruye todas las sesiones. Como resultado todos los estudiantes que iniciaron sesión se redirige automaticamente a index.html(login).

Este es el contenido de logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../index.html");
?>
```

y se ejecuta cada vez que alguien presiona el botón "salir"

Cómo evitar el cierre de las otras sesiones?

Comment: Puedes destruir una sesión específica haciendo un `unset( $_SESSION["login"] );`

Comment: vale y sólo me pregunto si es la forma habitual de hacer este tipo de procedimientos o hay una forma más avanzada?

Comment: Algo no está bien con tu sistema, porque las sesiones deben ser exclusivas de cada usuario y lo que hace uno no debería afectar a otros.

Comment: `$inactividad = 10;

if(isset($_SESSION["timeout"])){
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if($sessionTTL > $inactividad){
        header("Location: ../logout.php");
    }
}else{
  header("Location: ../logout.php");
}` Creo que era el tiempo que establecí para finalizar una sesión de usuario. Lo puse muy corto y se cerraba todas las sesiones que abría. Y no estaba reiniciando el contador cada vez que se invocaba la página `$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();`  Gracias por vuestros comentarios.

Comment: Al final me quedó así y va bien. `$inactividad = 600;

if(isset($_SESSION["timeout"])){
    $sessionTTL = time() - $_SESSION["timeout"];
    if($sessionTTL > $inactividad){
        header("Location: ../logout.php");
    }
}else{
  header("Location: ../logout.php");
}
$_SESSION["timeout"] = time();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion unset para borrar una unica sesion, algo asi `unset($_SESION['sesion'])`

Comment: vale y sólo me pregunto si es la forma habitual de hacer este tipo de procedimientos o hay una forma más avanzada?

Comment: Esa forma esta bien muy bien